# Line Separator not working inside Scroll View Android

Tags: android, xml

When Scroll View is included as root tag then the line separator which divides the screen exactly into two is not displayed. Otherwise its working fine.

Here is my layout file.

```
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/secondView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Goals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:text="Goals Scored- MANU"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SubButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="-" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Fouls"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:text="Fouls"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SubButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goalsscoredteamone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/foulsmadeteamone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/secondView"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#000000" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondView"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Goalsteam2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:text="Goals Scored MANC"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="+" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SubButton3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:text="-" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Foulsteam2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
            android:text="Fouls"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/AddButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:text="+" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/SubButton4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="-" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/goalsscoredteamtwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/foulsmadeteamtwo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Any work around needed or any possible solutions?

Comment: post your full xml we dont have magic powers here

Comment: I am just asking the logic behind this since scroll view will make height as a variable rather than fixed height which makes trouble for line seperator

Comment: so we need to assume that you have done everything perfectly in your lines and explain the logic .. if you think you have done everything right why you post a question?  wait another hour you wont get an answer if u do it in this way :D

Comment: Posted the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here goes the answer 
add `android:fillViewport="true"` to your `ScrollView` and it will work!

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >
    <ScrollView
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/firstLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/secondView"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Goals"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                    android:text="Goals Scored- MANU"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/AddButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="+" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/SubButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="-" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Fouls"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                    android:text="Fouls"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/AddButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="+" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/SubButton2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-" />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/goalsscoredteamone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/foulsmadeteamone"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/secondView"
                android:layout_width="1dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="#000000" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/thirdLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/secondView"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="8dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Goalsteam2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                    android:text="Goals Scored MANC"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/AddButton3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="+" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/SubButton3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:text="-" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/Foulsteam2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-smallcaps"
                    android:text="Fouls"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/AddButton4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:text="+" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/SubButton4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="-" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/goalsscoredteamtwo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/foulsmadeteamtwo"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


    </ScrollView>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: here is the logic that i copied xoxo "remember that android:layout_height=”fill_parent” means “set the height to the height of the parent.” This is obviously not what you want when using a ScrollView. After all, the ScrollView would become useless if its content was always as tall as itself. To work around this, you need to use the ScrollView attribute called android:fillViewport. When set to true, this attribute causes the scroll view’s child to expand to the height of the ScrollView if needed. When the child is taller than the ScrollView, the attribute has no effect."

Comment: Got it.Working well in portrait mode. In Landscape Mode I observed that line separator is missing. No problem with other behaviors though. Any idea?